# Javascript .reduce() tips? Is there a way to rename 'undefined' group?

Tags: javascript, reduce, simplify

I'm trying to understand the `.reduce()` function and the best way to go about the following.

I've got the following code:

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' },
  { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
  { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
];

const groupByCategory = products.reduce((group, product) => {
  const { category } = product;
  group[category] = group[category] ?? [];
  group[category].push(product);
  return group;
}, {});
```

I want to add a product with no 'category' property in it, and I want it pushed into a specific key rather than getting grouped in "undefined", so I edited it to:

```js
const products = [
  { name: "apples", category: "fruits" },
  { name: "oranges", category: "fruits" },
  { name: "potatoes", category: "vegetables" },
  { name: "guava"}
];

const groupByCategory = products.reduce((group, product) => {

  const { category } = product ;

  // check if 'category' exists, if it doesn't store it as an empty array to push to
  group[category] = group[category] ?? []; 
  
  // if category is undefined, push it into 'nocategory'. Otherwise push into relevant.
  if(!category){
     group['nocategory'].push(product);
  } else {
    group[category].push(product);
  };
  return group;
}, {'nocategory':[]});

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupByCategory, null, 2));
```

For the most part it works (there's still an 'undefined' group, but at least the object gets pushed into the right group).

I'm sure there's a better solution/proper way to do this. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a whole new conditional block you could just set a [default in the destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_value) and then group as usual.

```
const { category = 'nocategory' } = product;
```

```js
const products = [
  { name: "apples", category: "fruits" },
  { name: "oranges", category: "fruits" },
  { name: "potatoes", category: "vegetables" },
  { name: "guava"}
];

const groupByCategory = products.reduce((group, product) => {

  const { category = 'nocategory' } = product;
  group[category] ??= []; 
  group[category].push(product);

  return group;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupByCategory, null, 2));
```

*Note: you can also make use of [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the resource(s)! Time to do some reading.

Comment: ah, I knew there was a way to do it with nullish. I initally tried something along the lines of `group[category] = group[category] ?? noCategory: []` but quickly realised I  was working in the wrong area, which lead me to posting this question. Thanks for simplifying even further @pilchard

Answer (score 2):

You are creating undefined here

```
group[category] = group[category] ?? []; // category can be undefined
```

Move creation into if-else statement

```js
const products = [
  { name: "apples", category: "fruits" },
  { name: "oranges", category: "fruits" },
  { name: "potatoes", category: "vegetables" },
  { name: "guava"}
];

const groupByCategory = products.reduce((group, product) => {

  const { category } = product ;

  // check if 'category' exists, if it doesn't store it as an empty array to push to
  // removed
  
  // if category is undefined, push it into 'nocategory'. Otherwise push into relevant.
  if(!category){
     group['nocategory'].push(product);
  } else {
    group[category] = group[category] ?? [] // HERE
    group[category].push(product);
  };
  return group;
}, {'nocategory':[]});

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupByCategory, null, 2));
```